# issue in pl.polidea.coverflow when set android:targetSdkVersion>=14 (ICS)

Tags: android, coverflow

I m using pl.polidea.coverflow ( http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/ , which extends android.widget.Gallery ).

It is working well if I do not specify android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidMenifest..

If I specify android:targetSdkVersion as < 14, it is also working well..

but If I set android:targetSdkVersion as >=14, the behaviour of the coverflow gets mashed up.. it shows the centered Image at some angle (rotated image at some angel like side images in coverflow)..

this is main coverflow.java file.

```
    package pl.polidea.coverflow;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Camera;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Transformation;
    import android.widget.Gallery;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

    /**
     * Cover Flow implementation.
     * 
     */
    public class CoverFlow extends Gallery {

        /**
         * Graphics Camera used for transforming the matrix of ImageViews.
         */
        private final Camera mCamera = new Camera();

        /**
         * The maximum angle the Child ImageView will be rotated by.
         */
        private int mMaxRotationAngle = 30;  //default is 60

        /**
         * The maximum zoom on the centre Child.
         */
        private int mMaxZoom = -115;  //default is -120

        /**
         * The Centre of the Coverflow.
         */
        private int mCoveflowCenter;

        /** The image height. */
        private float imageHeight;

        /** The image width. */
        private float imageWidth;

        /** The reflection gap. */
        private float reflectionGap;

        /** The with reflection. */
        private boolean withReflection;

        /** The image reflection ratio. */
        private float imageReflectionRatio;

        /**
         * Gets the image height.
         * 
         * @return the image height
         */
        public float getImageHeight() {
            return imageHeight;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the image height.
         * 
         * @param imageHeight
         *            the new image height
         */
        public void setImageHeight(final float imageHeight) {
            this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the image width.
         * 
         * @return the image width
         */
        public float getImageWidth() {
            return imageWidth;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the image width.
         * 
         * @param imageWidth
         *            the new image width
         */
        public void setImageWidth(final float imageWidth) {
            this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the reflection gap.
         * 
         * @return the reflection gap
         */
        public float getReflectionGap() {
            return reflectionGap;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the reflection gap.
         * 
         * @param reflectionGap
         *            the new reflection gap
         */
        public void setReflectionGap(final float reflectionGap) {
            this.reflectionGap = reflectionGap;
        }

        /**
         * Checks if is with reflection.
         * 
         * @return true, if is with reflection
         */
        public boolean isWithReflection() {
            return withReflection;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the with reflection.
         * 
         * @param withReflection
         *            the new with reflection
         */
        public void setWithReflection(final boolean withReflection) {
            this.withReflection = withReflection;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the image reflection ratio.
         * 
         * @param imageReflectionRatio
         *            the new image reflection ratio
         */
        public void setImageReflectionRatio(final float imageReflectionRatio) {
            this.imageReflectionRatio = imageReflectionRatio;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the image reflection ratio.
         * 
         * @return the image reflection ratio
         */
        public float getImageReflectionRatio() {
            return imageReflectionRatio;
        }

        public CoverFlow(final Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
        }

        public CoverFlow(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.galleryStyle);
        }

        public CoverFlow(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            parseAttributes(context, attrs);
            this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
        }

        /**
         * Get the max rotational angle of the image.
         * 
         * @return the mMaxRotationAngle
         */
        public int getMaxRotationAngle() {
            return mMaxRotationAngle;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the.
         * 
         * @param adapter
         *            the new adapter
         */
        @Override
        public void setAdapter(final SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
            if (!(adapter instanceof AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The adapter should derive from "
                        + AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter.class.getName());
            }
            final AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter coverAdapter = (AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter) adapter;
            coverAdapter.setWidth(imageWidth);
            coverAdapter.setHeight((float)(imageHeight*(1.2)));
            if (withReflection) {
                final ReflectingImageAdapter reflectAdapter = new ReflectingImageAdapter(coverAdapter);
                reflectAdapter.setReflectionGap(reflectionGap);
                reflectAdapter.setWidthRatio(imageReflectionRatio);
                reflectAdapter.setWidth(imageWidth);
                reflectAdapter.setHeight(imageHeight * (1 + imageReflectionRatio));
                super.setAdapter(reflectAdapter);
            } else {
                super.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Set the max rotational angle of each image.
         * 
         * @param maxRotationAngle
         *            the mMaxRotationAngle to set
         */
        public void setMaxRotationAngle(final int maxRotationAngle) {
            mMaxRotationAngle = maxRotationAngle;
        }

        /**
         * Get the Max zoom of the centre image.
         * 
         * @return the mMaxZoom
         */
        public int getMaxZoom() {
            return mMaxZoom;
        }

        /**
         * Set the max zoom of the centre image.
         * 
         * @param maxZoom
         *            the mMaxZoom to set
         */
        public void setMaxZoom(final int maxZoom) {
            mMaxZoom = maxZoom;
        }

        /**
         * Get the Centre of the Coverflow.
         * 
         * @return The centre of this Coverflow.
         */
        private int getCenterOfCoverflow() {
            return (getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / 2 + getPaddingLeft();
        }

        /**
         * Get the Centre of the View.
         * 
         * @return The centre of the given view.
         */
        private static int getCenterOfView(final View view) {
            return view.getLeft() + view.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * 
         * @see #setStaticTransformationsEnabled(boolean)
         */
        @Override
        protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(final View child, final Transformation t) {

            final int childCenter = getCenterOfView(child);
            final int childWidth = child.getWidth();
            int rotationAngle = 0;

            t.clear();
            t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);

            if (childCenter == mCoveflowCenter) {
                transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, 0);
            } else {
                rotationAngle = (int) ((float) (mCoveflowCenter - childCenter) / childWidth * mMaxRotationAngle);
                if (Math.abs(rotationAngle) > mMaxRotationAngle) {
                    rotationAngle = rotationAngle < 0 ? -mMaxRotationAngle : mMaxRotationAngle;
                }
                transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, rotationAngle);
            }

            return true;
        }

        /**
         * This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If
         * you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old
         * values of 0.
         * 
         * @param w
         *            Current width of this view.
         * @param h
         *            Current height of this view.
         * @param oldw
         *            Old width of this view.
         * @param oldh
         *            Old height of this view.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh) {
            mCoveflowCenter = getCenterOfCoverflow();
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        /**
         * Transform the Image Bitmap by the Angle passed.
         * 
         * @param imageView
         *            ImageView the ImageView whose bitmap we want to rotate
         * @param t
         *            transformation
         * @param rotationAngle
         *            the Angle by which to rotate the Bitmap
         */
        private void transformImageBitmap(final ImageView child, final Transformation t, final int rotationAngle) {
            mCamera.save();
            final Matrix imageMatrix = t.getMatrix();

            final int height = child.getLayoutParams().height;

            final int width = child.getLayoutParams().width;
            final int rotation = Math.abs(rotationAngle);

            mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);

            // As the angle of the view gets less, zoom in
            if (rotation < mMaxRotationAngle) {
                final float zoomAmount = (float) (mMaxZoom + rotation * 1.5);
                mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, zoomAmount);
            }

            mCamera.rotateY(rotationAngle);
            mCamera.getMatrix(imageMatrix);
            imageMatrix.preTranslate(-(width / 2.0f), -(height / 2.0f));
            imageMatrix.postTranslate((width / 2.0f), (height / 2.0f));
            mCamera.restore();
        }

        /**
         * Parses the attributes.
         * 
         * @param context
         *            the context
         * @param attrs
         *            the attrs
         */
        private void parseAttributes(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
            final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CoverFlow);
            try {
                imageWidth = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CoverFlow_imageWidth, 480);
                imageHeight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CoverFlow_imageHeight, 320);
                withReflection = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CoverFlow_withReflection, false);
                imageReflectionRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CoverFlow_imageReflectionRatio, 0.4f);
                reflectionGap = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CoverFlow_reflectionGap, 4);
                setSpacing(-20);
                setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Seems to be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521115/coverflow-which-extends-gallery-deprecated-isnt-working-correctly-in-4-0-devi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just Changed the coverflow.java and it is done.. I'm now able to set android:targetSdkVersion as >=14..

this is the code for coverflow.java:

```
    package pl.polidea.coverflow;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Camera;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Transformation;
    import android.widget.Gallery;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

    /**
     * Cover Flow implementation.
     * 
     */
    public class CoverFlow extends Gallery {

        /**
         * Graphics Camera used for transforming the matrix of ImageViews.
         */
        private final Camera mCamera = new Camera();

        /**
         * The maximum angle the Child ImageView will be rotated by.
         */
        private int mMaxRotationAngle = 30;  //default is 60

        /**
         * The maximum zoom on the centre Child.
         */
        private int mMaxZoom = -115;  //default is -120

        /**
         * The Centre of the Coverflow.
         */
        private int mCoveflowCenter;

        /** The image height. */
        private float imageHeight;

        /** The image width. */
        private float imageWidth;

        /** The reflection gap. */
        private float reflectionGap;

        /** The with reflection. */
        private boolean withReflection;

        /** The image reflection ratio. */
        private float imageReflectionRatio;

        /**
         * Gets the image height.
         * 
         * @return the image height
         */
        public float getImageHeight() {
            return imageHeight;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the image height.
         * 
         * @param imageHeight
         *            the new image height
         */
        public void setImageHeight(final float imageHeight) {
            this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the image width.
         * 
         * @return the image width
         */
        public float getImageWidth() {
            return imageWidth;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the image width.
         * 
         * @param imageWidth
         *            the new image width
         */
        public void setImageWidth(final float imageWidth) {
            this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the reflection gap.
         * 
         * @return the reflection gap
         */
        public float getReflectionGap() {
            return reflectionGap;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the reflection gap.
         * 
         * @param reflectionGap
         *            the new reflection gap
         */
        public void setReflectionGap(final float reflectionGap) {
            this.reflectionGap = reflectionGap;
        }

        /**
         * Checks if is with reflection.
         * 
         * @return true, if is with reflection
         */
        public boolean isWithReflection() {
            return withReflection;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the with reflection.
         * 
         * @param withReflection
         *            the new with reflection
         */
        public void setWithReflection(final boolean withReflection) {
            this.withReflection = withReflection;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the image reflection ratio.
         * 
         * @param imageReflectionRatio
         *            the new image reflection ratio
         */
        public void setImageReflectionRatio(final float imageReflectionRatio) {
            this.imageReflectionRatio = imageReflectionRatio;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the image reflection ratio.
         * 
         * @return the image reflection ratio
         */
        public float getImageReflectionRatio() {
            return imageReflectionRatio;
        }

        public CoverFlow(final Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
        }

        public CoverFlow(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.galleryStyle);
        }

        public CoverFlow(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            parseAttributes(context, attrs);
            this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
        }

        /**
         * Get the max rotational angle of the image.
         * 
         * @return the mMaxRotationAngle
         */
        public int getMaxRotationAngle() {
            return mMaxRotationAngle;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the.
         * 
         * @param adapter
         *            the new adapter
         */
        @Override
        public void setAdapter(final SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
            if (!(adapter instanceof AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The adapter should derive from "
                        + AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter.class.getName());
            }
            final AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter coverAdapter = (AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter) adapter;
            coverAdapter.setWidth(imageWidth);
            coverAdapter.setHeight((float)(imageHeight*(1.2)));
            if (withReflection) {
                final ReflectingImageAdapter reflectAdapter = new ReflectingImageAdapter(coverAdapter);
                reflectAdapter.setReflectionGap(reflectionGap);
                reflectAdapter.setWidthRatio(imageReflectionRatio);
                reflectAdapter.setWidth(imageWidth);
                reflectAdapter.setHeight(imageHeight * (1 + imageReflectionRatio));
                super.setAdapter(reflectAdapter);
            } else {
                super.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Set the max rotational angle of each image.
         * 
         * @param maxRotationAngle
         *            the mMaxRotationAngle to set
         */
        public void setMaxRotationAngle(final int maxRotationAngle) {
            mMaxRotationAngle = maxRotationAngle;
        }

        /**
         * Get the Max zoom of the centre image.
         * 
         * @return the mMaxZoom
         */
        public int getMaxZoom() {
            return mMaxZoom;
        }

        /**
         * Set the max zoom of the centre image.
         * 
         * @param maxZoom
         *            the mMaxZoom to set
         */
        public void setMaxZoom(final int maxZoom) {
            mMaxZoom = maxZoom;
        }

        /**
         * Get the Centre of the Coverflow.
         * 
         * @return The centre of this Coverflow.
         */
        private int getCenterOfCoverflow() {
            return (getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / 2 + getPaddingLeft();
        }

        /**
         * Get the Centre of the View.
         * 
         * @return The centre of the given view.
         */
        private static int getCenterOfView(final View view) {
            return view.getLeft() + view.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * 
         * @see #setStaticTransformationsEnabled(boolean)
         */
        @Override
        protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(final View child, final Transformation t) {


            mCoveflowCenter = getCenterOfCoverflow();
            final int childCenter = getCenterOfView(child)
                    + offsetChildrenLeftAndRight();
            final int childWidth = child.getWidth();

            int rotationAngle = 0;

            t.clear();
            t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
            // FacyLog.writeToLog("mCoveflowCenter : "+mCoveflowCenter+" , childCenter:"+childCenter+" , difference : "+(mCoveflowCenter
            // - childCenter)+" , ");
            if ((mCoveflowCenter - childCenter) < 45
                    && (mCoveflowCenter - childCenter) > -45) {
                transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, 0);
                Log.i("rotation angel", "rotation angel : 0");
                // FacyLog.writeToLog("rotation angel : 0");
            } else {
                rotationAngle = (int) (((float) (mCoveflowCenter - childCenter) / childWidth) * mMaxRotationAngle);
                if (Math.abs(rotationAngle) > mMaxRotationAngle) {
                    rotationAngle = (rotationAngle < 0) ? -mMaxRotationAngle
                            : mMaxRotationAngle;
                }
                transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, rotationAngle);
                Log.i("rotation angel", "rotation angel : " + rotationAngle);
                // FacyLog.writeToLog("rotation angel : "+rotationAngle);
            }
            // FacyLog.writeToLog("\n");

            return true;
        }

        private int offsetChildrenLeftAndRight() {
            int offset = 0;
            for (int i = getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                getChildAt(i).offsetLeftAndRight(offset);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    getChildAt(i).invalidate();
            }
            return offset;
        }

        /**
         * This is called during layout when the size of this view has changed. If
         * you were just added to the view hierarchy, you're called with the old
         * values of 0.
         * 
         * @param w
         *            Current width of this view.
         * @param h
         *            Current height of this view.
         * @param oldw
         *            Old width of this view.
         * @param oldh
         *            Old height of this view.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh) {
            mCoveflowCenter = getCenterOfCoverflow();
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        /**
         * Transform the Image Bitmap by the Angle passed.
         * 
         * @param imageView
         *            ImageView the ImageView whose bitmap we want to rotate
         * @param t
         *            transformation
         * @param rotationAngle
         *            the Angle by which to rotate the Bitmap
         */
        private void transformImageBitmap(final ImageView child, final Transformation t, final int rotationAngle) {
            mCamera.save();
            final Matrix imageMatrix = t.getMatrix();

            final int height = child.getLayoutParams().height;

            final int width = child.getLayoutParams().width;
            final int rotation = Math.abs(rotationAngle);

            mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);

            // As the angle of the view gets less, zoom in
            if (rotation < mMaxRotationAngle) {
                final float zoomAmount = (float) (mMaxZoom + rotation * 1.5);
                mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, zoomAmount);
            }

            mCamera.rotateY(rotationAngle);
            mCamera.getMatrix(imageMatrix);
            imageMatrix.preTranslate(-(width / 2.0f), -(height / 2.0f));
            imageMatrix.postTranslate((width / 2.0f), (height / 2.0f));
            mCamera.restore();
        }

        /**
         * Parses the attributes.
         * 
         * @param context
         *            the context
         * @param attrs
         *            the attrs
         */
        private void parseAttributes(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
            final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CoverFlow);
            try {
                imageWidth = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CoverFlow_imageWidth, 480);
                imageHeight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CoverFlow_imageHeight, 320);
                withReflection = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CoverFlow_withReflection, false);
                imageReflectionRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CoverFlow_imageReflectionRatio, 0.4f);
                reflectionGap = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CoverFlow_reflectionGap, 4);
                setSpacing(-20);
                setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }

    }
```